# Definition of the power of a representation, what is the product rule taken here

Tags: representation-theory

Here is a definition of a "power" or at least it uses a power notation, of a representation.

Context : we consider $S_3$ and we say $p_T$ is the representation that is in direct sum with the trivial representation in the permutation representation. This representation is also called standard representation over $\mathbb{C^3}$,  we can define it by $\left\{c_1e_1+c_2e_2+c_3e_3, \sum c_i=0 \right\}$.

The author defines :
we say that $p^2$ is Hom($p_T,p_T$) and for all integer $n\geq 3$, $p^n$ is the representation Hom($p^{n-1},p_T$).

But for example, let's take $n=4$.

It would give me litteraly something that is written like $$\mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Hom}(p_T,p_T)*p_T,p_T).$$ (Or I don't understand what the definition tries to say as for me the cases are not defined literally for $n \geq 3$.)

**What would be the meaning of my "$*$" here ? Literally we compare a morphism and a vector space (in the sense that for me, Hom($p_a,p_b$) just means Hom($A,B$) where $p_A$ and $p_B$ are just some representations and $A$, $B$ their related vector space.)**

Comment: If $n=3$ then $p^3$, according to your definition, is $\hom(p^2,p)$, which in turn is $\hom(\hom(p,p),p)$. Contrary to what you've written, there is no "$\ast p$" in this last expression.

Comment: This is a very weird and non-standard definition. Normally you would take the tensor product as the definition, and then $Hom(p,p)$ is the product of $p$ with its dual. Here $p$ is isomorphic to its dual, so it does give the same result, but it does not need to be the case for any representation.

Comment: Thanks , I understood. Seems my mind was stucked on something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @runway44, @captain lama 2 , the answer to what i was stucked on :

As it's defined by reccurence , $p^3$ is well defined and so $p^4$ , ...